# Dynamic Window Size with DIV proportional to second DIV

Tags: css, html

I have a window that can be resized. Within: there is a div that must change size as the window changes. There is an OK bar of height whatever content inside that must always appear at the bottom. Note that content for these 2 can be changed at any time. Please no javascript solutions.

```
<html style=height:100%> 
<body style=height:100%;overflow:hidden> 
<div id=edit_area style=height:80%;overflow-y:auto>Unknown content and height</div>
<div id=ok_bar style=height:100px>Unknown content and height</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Despite what some say - a table was an EASY solution for this before html5 >:

Comment: Please do not use inline styles this is so poor.

Answer (score 1):

Please, as i said, do not use inline style.

**CSS File:**

```
html{
  height:100%;
}

body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div#edit_area{
  height:80%;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
div#ok_bar{
  height:20%;
  position:relative;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html> 
<body> 
<div id=edit_area>Unknown content and height</div>
<div id=ok_bar>Unknown content and height</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Totally did not answer my question.

Comment: The 80% will not maintain flush contact with the bottom div when the window changes

Comment: see edit @JohnnyDarvall ps: your question is hard to understand

Comment: Sorry about that - mabey the code below makes sense - a dynamically re-sizable content area with a fixed bar at the bottom....

Answer (score 0):

This worked using a table:

```
    <style>html,body{height:100%}</style>
    <body style=padding:0;overflow:hidden>
    <table style=width:100%;height:100%>
    <tr><td style=padding:0>
<div style='height:100%;overflow:auto;padding:20px' contentEditable></div>
</td></tr>
    <tr><td style=height:10px;padding:8px><input type=button value=OK></td></tr>
    </table>
    </body></html>
```